# How to extract values from a java properties files in a bash/shell script and store in a variable and cd to that variable

Tags: shell, properties, grep, cd

I have a config.properties file which contains a path like `ouputdir=/data1/testdata/output`. I am able to extract these in shell and store this path in a variable. While I am trying to change directory to this path, I am getting error something like: `No such file or directory/data1/testdata/output`, thouth this path exists.

What I tried is:

```
configPath=/data1/testdata.config.properties
my_value=$(grep outputdir $configPath|  awk -F= '{print $2}')
echo $my_value
cd $my_value
```

by this I am able to print the path in my_value variable.but I am not able to change directory to $my_value.can anybody tell me what is wrong here and how can I change directory to this variable.

Answer (score 2):

What you have should work. Check the obvious, that the directory is spelled right and does exist.

For what it's worth, you could combine the grep and awk commands into one:

```
my_value=$(awk -F= '$1=="outputdir" {print $2}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your properties file have windows CRLF line endings? your script may think the directory is `/data1/testdata/output^M` with the trailing carriage return.

```
sed -n '/^outputdir=/{s///; s/\r$//; p; q}' properties.file
```